# C# Help about Forms

Tags: c#

I want to make a program that if we click on a location for example : -2, 0 , a function will be done.

P.S. : The clicking event is on the form. So, should I use timer?

Comment: You really need to post some code here - tell us what kind of controls you are using to display your location data and what you've already tried, if anything.  There's very very little here for anyone to go on to begin to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jakub says, use the forms click event. You can find this here:

[image: Click Event]

When you click anywhere on the form, you get the location of the click passed in as X and Y co-ordinates in the event args, as well as which mouse button was clicked, like so:

[image: Event Args]

Answer (score 1):

No, just attach the handler to `OnClick` event on the Form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A mouse click will give you the mouse position.

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseClick);
void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X == -2 && e.Y == 0)
        ; // Do function.
}
```